# Is there any extension available in the Jupyter Notebook for automatically linting the Python code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, lint, pep8

I'm currently using Jupyter Notebook for my Python development work, and I'm looking for a way to automatically lint my Python code within the notebook environment. Linting helps catch syntax errors, style issues, and potential bugs in the code, which is crucial for maintaining clean and reliable code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Excellent Question**

I typically use Visual Studio, and it offers the convenience of running Jupyter Notebook directly. Visual Studio provides several advantages, such as offering information when you hover over functions, tabbing assistance, quotes, and more.

However, if you desire even greater functionality, you can enhance Visual Studio by installing **"IntelliSense"** along with **"Pylance."** and **[Flake 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/pvsc-sept-2022/)** Check official information about this in a blog post from Microsoft.

Cheers

Comment: Please do not answer [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) questions. Instead, flag them for closure as such.